# Tracking data sent to remote host over time?

Tags: networking, http, linux-networking, network-monitoring, imap

What is a a good way to track over time the amount of data transferred from my Linux server to another host on the internet? https and imaps only

Answer (score 1):

For example [darkstat](http://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) can do this. It's main features are:

- **Traffic graphs, reports per host, shows ports for each host.**
- Embedded web-server with deflate compression.
- Asynchronous reverse DNS resolution using a child process.
- Small. Portable. Single-threaded. Efficient.
- Supports IPv6.